# How can use custom_variable_class

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.1

i am create `custom_variable_class= myapp` in `postgresql.conf`. And set the value is inside of function like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_purchase(xmode text, xuserno integer)
  RETURNS text AS

set myapp.user_no=xuserno
..........
..........

END;
```

Now i am using myapp.user in my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_history()
  RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$
    DECLARE userno text;
    BEGIN

    SELECT current_setting('myapp.user_no') into userno;
END;
$BODY$
```

If set `userno` is `integer` then it show error message.

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "xuserno".
```

and
 `SELECT current_setting('myapp.user_no')` is show `xuserno` not `xuserno value`. That means `xuserno=5` it show `xuserno` not `5`. I am doing any thing wrong?

Comment: Try `PERFORM set_config('myapp.user_no', xuserno::text, 'f'::boolean)` instead of `SET`.

Comment: It show same result. so i try to change the name like `myapp.user-no1` that time it show error `unrecognized configuration parameter myapp.user_no`. what i am doing wrong

Comment: Since you haven't provided the complete and unmodified code you're running I really cannot help you any more. Provide a self-contained, complete and unmodified example that shows the problem exactly as you run it on your computer. (`.......` is not valid PL/PgSQL). Or just use the `TEMPORARY TABLE` approach.

Comment: @CraigRinger You probably do, but you realise `'f'::boolean` can be written `false`? Seems a lot more readable...

Comment: @IMSoP Huh, nope; I didn't realise that'd been added to the syntax at some point. Sometimes using a package for a long time has downsides...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a very subtle one:

According to the docs instead of:

```
 custom_variable_class= myapp
```

You should have

```
custom_variable_classes='myapp'
```

Note that `custom_variable_classes` is intended to be used to set multiple classes for multiple addons.

From there, with the comments above, this should work.